# Parse HTML with Html.fromHtml

Tags: android, html, spanned

I have a `TextView` in my application and some HTML text.
This text contains symbols like "<" or ">" and HTML tags.

Here's a sample:

```
<P>very often (>1/10), often (>1/100, <1/10), not often (>1/1000, <1/100), rarely (>1/10000, <1/1000), very rarely (1/10000, including individual)</P>
```

I've tried to use `Html.fromHtml` method and it returns me an incorrect text:

```
very often (>1/10), often (>1/100, 1/1000, 1/10000),
```

My question is: how can I parse html using `Html.fromHtml` to avoid this situation?
Or is there any another ways to parse HTML?

Comment: "There's a sample" -- that is invalid HTML. Those angle brackets need to be turned into HTML entities (`&lt`; and `&gt;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&lt;` (read: "less than") to replace `<`, and `&gt;` (read: "greater than") to replace `>`.